# Wordpress dynamic url for same page template

Tags: php, wordpress, url

I have created page template in wordpress. right now its url is static like `http://localhost/wordpress/test-test1` but i want to make it dynamic like `http://localhost/wordpress/test1-test-test2` . Is it possible to create a single page template having dynamic url??

I want both url's to comes on single page. If page templating approach is not good then what could be other approaches. Here the test urls:

http://localhost/wordpress/test-test1

http://localhost/wordpress/test1-test-test2

http://localhost/wordpress/test13-test2-test1

I found similar links but none of the link helped me.

Comment: Content is being shown by templates, think about them like objects and url's act like pointers. So you want to have many pointers to one object. You have to set them point to one object somehow. Templating approach is the only one way I can see in pure wordpress.

Answer (score 2):

Here it depends on how would you change to pass argument, Suppose the last stage and it should be same always, and let page name 'anything'

```
<?php
    add_action('init', 'add_my_rule');

    function add_my_rule()
    {
        global $wp;
        $wp->add_query_var('args');

        add_rewrite_rule('test\/laststage\/(.*)','index.php?pagename=Pagename&args=$matches[1]','top');
```

Apply your custom template to this page, & on that template use this:

```
//if you visit http://.../test/laststage/name/AnyName, thus this $params will be name/AnyName.Now need to explode this and get the value.

$params = get_query_var('args');
```

Here's info: http://www.workingwith.me.uk/articles/scripting/mod_rewrite